# has many relationship through with Core Data

Tags: sql, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, core-data, magicalrecord

Let's say I have 3 models: Hotel, Category and Room.
A hotel has many categories and a category has many rooms.

I want to get an array of all the room numbers for a specific hotel.

In Rails, with ActiveRecord I would have the following:

```
class Hotel
  has_many :categories
  has_many :rooms, through: :categories
end
class Category
  has_many :rooms
end
```

and then, if I have a hotel object, the query would be as simple as:

```
hotel.rooms.map(&:room_number)
```

And I would get an array of room numbers for the hotel.

How can I achieve the same thing with Objective-C and Core Data? Can MagicalRecord help with this type of abstraction? Do I have to write the SQL statement directly because the current ORMs don't support anything like this?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Have you begun to write the Objective-C code?

Comment: I haven't. I can write the SQL query directly or do something like fetch the categories for the hotel first and then do a second query to get the room for the fetched categories. I am just wondering whether there is an obvious way to do it at a higher level like ActiveRecord that I might be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the relationships are define like this:

[image]

you can use "Key-Value Coding" to get all room numbers for a given hotel:

```
Hotel *theHotel = ...;
NSSet *setOfRoomNumbers = [theHotel valueForKeyPath:@"categories.@distinctUnionOfSets.rooms.roomNumber"];
// And if you need an array instead of a set:
NSArray *arrayOfRoomNumbers = [setOfRoomNumbers allObjects];
```

A disadvantage of this method is that it fetches all categories first and then the rooms.

Alternatively, you can execute a fetch request for the "Room" entity, using the
inverse relationships:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Room"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.hotel == %@", theHotel];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSArray *rooms = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSArray *roomNumbers = [rooms valueForKey:@"roomNumber"];
```

With Magical Record, this would probably look like (untested):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.hotel == %@", theHotel];
NSArray *rooms = [Room MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *roomNumbers = [rooms valueForKey:@"roomNumber"];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The missing piece for me was that we could chain in predicates like @"category.hotel == %@". I was not aware of the KVO option on entities and although I am not sure I understand it entirely, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any SQL queries with Core Data and especially with Magical Record.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Fetching.md) to a documentation on how to fetch objects and relationships.

A simple example would be this:

```
NSArray *rooms = @[@1, @2, @3, @4];
NSPredicate *roomFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Rooms IN %@", rooms];

NSArray *rooms = [Person MR_findAllWithPredicate:roomFilter];
```

This is just an example code, don't treat as a fully working and tested solution.

Comment: I am aware of that but I am asking about a specific case when I have 3 models with has many relationships. Is there an simple way to write the predicate in that case to handle the chaining?